# System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr, badimageformatexception

I currently am trying to connect to a SignalR Asp.net Core 3.1 service from my WPF application. The code works fine until I create a .msi file and try to install it. I am using the Visual Studio Installer Projects.

If I create a build and run it, everything works fine and the WPF-App connects to the SignalR service as it should. I tried copying the build/release folder to another computer which worked fine aswell.

Where the code crashes:

```
try
{
   _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
         .WithUrl(uri)
         .WithAutomaticReconnect()
         .Build();
 }
    catch (Exception e)
 {
```

Error:

System.BadImageFormatException: The Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces file or assembly or a dependency on it was not found. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in a loading context for reflection only. (HRESULT exception: 0x80131058)

The WPF project is referencing a .Net Standard 2.0 project and is running on .Net Framework 4.7.2

So my question:

Is there a known problem with the Visual Studio Installer Projects. I assume its the Installer Project, because the project works fine if I just use it without the installer.

Comment: When I had this exception in the past, it was usually because the TargetPlatform property of the installer project was not set to the correct value so it was incompatible to the external library.

Comment: @Đøharrrck I will check that out, it's strange because the installer was working for more than a year without any problems.

Comment: Changing the TargetPlatform did not really do anything. Still encountering the same error.

Comment: Having the same issue in 2023, an installer project working for years suddenly cause  BadImageFormatException. Did you find any solution?